# How to enable animations for 3D models in A-frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have a simple code, I load a 3D model and I want to attach it some animation to move from A point to B point. But I don't know what is missing.... This animation even don't start...

```
    <a-scene>
        <a-assets>

        <a-asset-item id="cowlowpoly" src="cow2/lowpolycow/cow.obj"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>

        <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cowlowpoly;" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"   rotation="0.0 -90 0.0" position="0.0 0.0 -2.0">
          <a-animation attribute="position" dur="3000" from="0.0 0.0 -2.0" to="0.0 0.0 -20.0" repeat="indefinite">
          </a-animation>
        </a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

Comment: Without code is hard to help and suggest solutions. https://glitch.com/~aframe Keep in mind that a-animation has been deprecated in favor of the [animation component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#sidebar)

Comment: @DiegoMarcos this is the code :) I want this model, which is loaded and all is ok to move a bit.

Comment: I recommend sharing full code that people can run and debug with https://glitch.com/~aframe otherwise it will be hard to help

Comment: @engineer try re-writing it with the [animation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#sidebar) component instead of `<a-animation>` and let us know if you have any trouble along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        <a-entity obj-model="obj: #cowlowpoly;"
                  scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"
                  rotation="0.0 -90 0.0"
                  position="0.0 0.0 -2.0"
                  animation="property: position;
                             dur: 3000;
                             from: 0.0 0.0 -2.0;
                             to: 0.0 0.0 -20.0;
                             loop: true">
        </a-entity>
```

The script `<a-animation></a-animation>` is outdated and is not reliable, even though many the online tutorials use it (mainly because they are old tutorials).